# TornadoFX: Label text not updating

Tags: javafx, label, kotlin, tornadofx

One of the issues I'm currently experiencing is that I can't seem to change the text of a Label which is implemented in a dynamically loaded `AnchorPane`. I assume this might be related to the controller and how JavaFX/TornadoFX works, but I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong.

The issue itself occurs in [this class](https://github.com/sigmadeltasoftware/APT-InItFX/blob/feature/APTFX-3-Create-system-details-view/src/main/kotlin/be/sigmadelta/aptinitfx/presentation/systemdetails/SystemDetailsViewProxy.kt), and happens in the `showSystemDetails()` method. What I would expect to happen is that upon pressing the "System Details" button in the sidebar, the labels would update to the required value, but this isn't happening for some reason.

Please feel free to point me to what I'm doing wrong, or provide any constructive criticism. The project is still in full development so a lot of things are still messy/broken.

Comment: You have removed the SystemDetailsViewProxy.kt class from HEAD now, so I'ts hard to test. Can you put it back perhaps?

Comment: Hey Edvin, please try checking out the `feature/APTFX-3-Create-system-details-view` branch. Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is that you're manually loading a new version of the FMXL file every time you select something in your menu. The FXML file originally loaded by `SystemDetailsViewProxy` is updated correctly, but that's not the one you're showing on screen anymore.

To see the updated View, make sure you put the root node of the `SystemDetailsViewProxy` instance back.

You could for example change your DrawerMenuButton enum to contain references to SystemDetailsViewProxy::class instead of those two strings, and use `add(viewClass)` to add the correct root node to your view when clicking the menu buttons.

Furthermore, you should be using ViewModels and binding instead of manually updating the text property of the labels. You're doing an awful lot of manual/error prone work that the framework can help you with for free.

Your application is not using best practices in several important areas, and you're rolling your own solutions for stuff that the framework already does very well :)

Views are singletons when managed by the framework, but you instantiate them yourself instead of using inject/find. The result is that important life cycle methods are not being called.

I would also suggest looking into type safe builders instead of FXML.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey Edvin, thank you very much for the clarification and the additional remarks! Looks like I'll have to look a little bit further into JavaFX & TornadoFX to get a better grasp on how it's structured.

Comment: Great :) If you have questions or need guidance, you should join us on Slack! https://kotlinlang.slack.com/messages/tornadofx/